# Pull To Refresh Horizontal iScroll

Tags: iscroll4

Recently I successfully integrate vertical [iScroll](http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=iscroll4&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4&ei=fbNIUJ_dHO-KmQWV74DICw&usg=AFQjCNFKjfacOGWvwnoiXyAXZlxT2aZd7w) to my mobile web. It has pull to refresh feature. However, Im currently stack at the part which I need to implement the same feature into a **horizontal iScroll**. Does anyone knows where can I see any sample that uses the same feature? I really need the help. All I need is to know how to do it because as of now, i have no idea with it.

Regards,
Askhole :)

Answer (score 0):

iScroll by default does not support Pull to Refresh from a horizontal standpoint. I'm sure it could be done with some CSS and code tweaks, but you might be better off asking in the iScroll forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/iscroll

Answer (score -1):

i guess you implement vertical refresh by using a non-official iscroll.js (i.e., a modified-for-refresh iscroll). If this is your situation, this answer may helps:

i implemented vertical refresh with the official iscroll.js, by adding a little trick:
1. keep sth very very tiny at the next-bottom, use its position().top to detect the actual height of ur page

2. keep you "onloading" ath the bottom, set it invisible
3. Math.abs(myScroll.y) + wrapper.height === $(yourTiny).position().top
4. when scroll starts, if scroll upwards, check the condition in 3.
5. for tolerance in 4, you may use, for example: if(Math.abs(myScroll.y - wrapper.height + $(yourTiny).position().top) < 11){ //your code to refresh}

Here are the sample codes:

1.html

```
      <sapn id="theTinyThing">&nbsp;</span>
      <table id="bottomRefreshImg" style="display:none">
        <tr><td><img src="refreshGreen.gif" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>loading...</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div> //close scroller
  </div>  //close wrapper
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <script src="./jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./iscroll.js"></script>
  <script src="./mrPage.js"></script>
</body>
```

2.css

```
#theTinyThing{
  height:1px; //it's ivisible
  font-size:1px;
}
```

3.js

```
var myScroll;
var myScroolHasCausedAddNew=0;

function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
                   scrollbars: true,
                   scrollbars: 'custom',
                   mouseWheel: true,
                   click:true,
                   interactiveScrollbars: true,
                   shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
                   fadeScrollbars: true,
                   snap:true,
                   snap:'table',
    });
    myScroll.on('scrollStart',function(){
        if($("#theTinyThing").position().top + myScroll.y-myScroll.wrapperHeight<11){
            if(myScroll.directionY==1){
                $("#bottomRefreshImg").show();
                myScroolHasCausedAddNew=1;
            }
        }       
        return false;
    });
    myScroll.on('scrollEnd',function(){
        if(myScroolHasCausedAddNew==1){
            myScroolHasCausedAddNew=0;
            $("#bottomRefreshImg").hide();
            loadMore();
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```